# I want to connect firebase with mongodb as alternative of algolia search?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a big project and I want to use firebase storage and full Text search like algolia or elastic search search but want to use mongoDb due to price and some more issue so how can my firebase database send data to mongoDb and How can I pass query to mongoDb

Comment: The question is super vague and like Firebase, MongoDB is a bunch of different services so we don't know to which you're referring. Also, why don't you use just one platform instead of several? That will reduce your code base and make the product easier to manage. Lastly, do you have a coding issue? That's what we do here so please include the code you've attempted. I would suggest updating and clarifying the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the firebase cloud function to save data on MongoDB on data insert and update in firebase.then you can easily query on mongodb for full text search.

Comment: While that sounds great, it will *double* the costs as data will now be stored in two different platforms.

Comment: Agreed with @Jay

Answer (score -1):

you can not perform a search on Firestore or Realtime Database, it's totally fine to have searchable data duplicated in a different DB. Algolia and Mongo Atlas search are good solutions to use. You need to keep in sync a firestore collection with whatever solution you want to use for search, just create a function the triggers onWrite and insert/update the record.

"functions.store" has ready to use function the keep collection sync with Algolia

Comment: This is incorrect. Of course you can perform a search on Firestore or Realtime Database! See [Perform Simple and Compound Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). If you are so inclined you can even do a partial "starts with" string search or if you really want to do it, a full string search.

Comment: I was talking about full string search, of course you can create queries that filter documents based on certain operators, but is that a real search :) ... in my opinion is very limited if you want to meet customer exceptions of what is a search.

Comment: Many use cases are auto-fill. For example where a user starts to type a word and the app auto-fills or auto-completes the rest of the word, or shows options based on what they typed. Firebase products can definitely do that. Perhaps clarifying the answer would be appropriate for future readers.